# Asus P7P55-M is not recognizing memory in slots 2, 3 and 4

Tags: memory, motherboard

I am running an asus p7p55-m motherboard with 2x 2GB Gskill sticks of RAM.  But my motherboard is only detecting the memory in the first slot.

Do I have to configure BIOS correctly? If not how do I fix it?
If I do changes what else could be the problem?

I have tried msconfig and resetting my RAM many times but nothing has worked.  I can't post a picture till now...  But on my CPUZ it is showing

JEDEC #2 - 533 MHz,  JEDEC #3 - 609 MHz,  JEDEC #4 - 666 MHz,  XMP-1600  -800 MHz

Comment: See My Edits and add the pictures of CPUZ result.

Answer (score 0):

Go to BIOS setting and do

`FAIL-SAFE DEFAULT SETTING` and save and exit from bios setting. then try restarting your CPU,

also try changing RAM to different slot might be one of your RAM stick isn't functioning.

[image: Ram desc]

> JEDEC #2 - 533 MHz, JEDEC #3 - 609 MHz, JEDEC #4 - 666 MHz, XMP-1600 -800 MHz

This will be shown to each slots

the drop down list which is beneath the Memory Slot Selection will show the detectable RAM in each slot.

The above picture shows the Slot 1 desc. see this in your system is Slot #2 is detecting the Ram or Not?
Slot#1

Answer (score 0):

> motherboard is only detecting the memory in the first slot.
>   Do I have to configure BIOS correctly?

No. Using default settings your BIOS should recognise all the memory. Same for UEFI (you motherboard has no BIOS, it has UEFI firmwware).

If it does not then either:

1. The memory module is of the wrong kind (e.g. DDR3 in a DD3L-only system)
2. The memory module is broken.
3. The connector for the memory (or the copper traces to it) are broken.
4. Or the memory controller (these days on the CPU, previously on the north bridge part of the chipset) is broken.
5. Or you manually configured the BIOS to use specific settings which are not compatible with the memory.

I read the question as having two identical memory modules. That rules out possibility 1. possibility 2 can be checked by swapping the memory modules. If it works then you know you have two working DIMMs.

Possibility 3: broken connectors are possible, but three of them? Unlikely.

Possibility 4: Memory controller failed: Also unlikely, and only testable by changing the CPU. (The P755M is a modern LGA1156 platform, the memory controller is on the die that also contains the CPU).

THat leaves option 5 as the most likely. Entering the motherboard firmware (UEFI) and resetting memory settings.

> I have tried msconfig

No use. If it is not detected in UEFI then it is also not detected in the OS.

> and resetting my RAM many times but nothing has worked.

I am not sure what 'resetting RAM' means. Reseating it?

> I can't post a picture till now... But CPUZ it is showing
>   JEDEC #2 - 533 MHz, JEDEC #3 - 609 MHz, JEDEC #4 - 666 MHz, XMP-1600 -800 MHz

Those are just the settings for the memory module which it did recognize (hence the 'slot 1' in the top left corner. You can open that and see the settings for the other memory modules. If they do not show up then those are not recognised.

That leaves you with only a few tasks:
1) Check that both modules re working by swapping them.
2) If you have a spare CPU, or one you can borrow, test for a broken CPU.
3) RMA the motherboard. This is most likely.